# String to List of Int

Tags: string, haskell, int

I would like to incorporate Maybe [int] into this.

The code should take a string and filter out spaces turning it into a list of integers and if their are letters return Nothing.

```
text2digits :: String -> [Int]
text2digits s = case s of
    []          -> []
    x:xs        
        |isDigit x      -> digitToInt x :text2digits (filter (/= ' ') xs)
        |otherwise      -> undefined

input "1233 5687"  output: [1,2,3,3,5,6,8,7]
input "a89"       required output : Nothing 
                  current output: undefined
```

I have tried this but it shows up a list of errors

```
text2digits :: String -> Maybe [Int]
text2digits s = case s of
    []          -> Just []
        x:xs        
        |isDigit x      -> Just digitToInt x :text2digits (filter (/= ' ') xs)
        |otherwise      -> Nothing
```

Comment: Specify what's wrong with your current code. Provide an example of input and expected output.

Comment: In your `otherwise` case, return `Nothing`. That will, however, require you to change the return type of the `isDigit` case, and the `[]` case, to `Maybe [Int]` as well. You can do that by using `Just`.

Comment: You can not merge a `Nothing` with a list...

Answer (score 5):

What is wrong with the code, that you've specified for `text2digits :: String -> Maybe [Int]`?

The problem is in this line:

```
digitToInt x :text2digits (filter (/= ' ') xs)
```

`text2digits` returns value of `Maybe [Int]` type, but `(:)` expects it to be `[Int]`.

In order to fix it, you can use `fmap` or `<$>` to apply a function to a structure inside the functor `Maybe`:

```
import Data.Char

text2digits :: String -> Maybe [Int]
text2digits s = case s of
    [] -> Just []
    x:xs
      |isDigit x      -> ((digitToInt x) :) <$> text2digits (filter (/= ' ') xs)
      |otherwise      -> Nothing

main = print $ text2digits "1233 5687"
```

Or probably you can use [traverse](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html#v:traverse) to refactor the function a bit:

```
import Data.Char

text2digits :: String -> Maybe [Int]
text2digits s =
  traverse digitToMaybeInt $ filter (/= ' ') s
  where
    digitToMaybeInt x
      | isDigit x = Just $ digitToInt x
      | otherwise = Nothing

main = print $ text2digits "89"
```